# CURLE_GOT_NOTHING in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, curl, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2005, libcurl

I run some gui's using curl, I worked on them sucessufully in **vs 2005**. But when I migrated to **vs2012** , response of  curl_easy_perform is always CURLE_GOT_NOTHING.

```
if(curl) 
        {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,URL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ZoomArg);
        res =curl_easy_perform(curl);
        }
```

PS:

1. Same code worked well for me in VS2005.
2. I build CURL in 2012 in release mode .
3. CGI in URL is being performed(Actually talking to CAM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I found the solution. We need to Download updated version / latest version of Curl to get supported by vs2012.It worked for me